# Radio buttons and checkboxes in VB

Tags: vb.net

The problem I have is:

I have 3 group boxes. In the first group box I have 3 radio buttons options with value of 1,1.50,1 and in the second group box I have 3 radio buttons more with almost the same values. In groupbox 3, I have 7 checkboxes all with values and a subtotal box, tax box, and the total with the tax.

The question will be when the user choses from every groupbox which variable will be used to store the data from the subtotal.

```
Private Sub btnTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTotal.Click

    tax = 0.07
    If rd1.Checked = True Then
        pan &= "1.00"
    End If
    If rd2.Checked = True Then
        bread &= "1.50"
    End If
    If rd3.Checked = True Then
        softdrink &= "0.85"
    End If
    If checkbox1.Checked = True Then
        ingredients &= "0.50"
        subtotal = ?
        subtotalTxtBox.Text = subtotal
        taxTxtBox.Text = tax
        total = subtotal * tax
        totalTxtBox.Text = subtotal + total
```

Comment: Can you try to clarify your question please? I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: ok sorry for that what im trying to do is from whatever radio button is selected from groupbox 1, 2, 3 takes those values and put in subtotal box. like 1+2+3 subtotal = 6

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.  Have you posted the complete code ?  Its missing and "End" for a start.

Comment: Sorry for that Rohit Gupta and yes i left the End on the code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example showing how to get the selected RadioButton from each GroupBox:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rb1 As RadioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(GroupBox1)
    Dim rb2 As RadioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(GroupBox2)
    Dim rb3 As RadioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(GroupBox3)

    If Not IsNothing(rb1) Then
        Debug.Print(rb1.Text)
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(rb2) Then
        Debug.Print(rb2.Text)
    End If
    If Not IsNothing(rb3) Then
        Debug.Print(rb3.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetSelectedRadioButton(ByVal gb As GroupBox) As RadioButton
    Return gb.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).Where(Function(x)
                                                        Return x.Checked
                                                    End Function).FirstOrDefault
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but why im trying to do is to press 3 radio button and takes those numbers like rb1 is  $1.00 + rb2 is $0.85 + rb3 is $0.50 add that sum  to a subtotal box.

Comment: Okay...my code showed you how to get which 3 RadioButtons were selected.  Just take the values and add them up now...what's keeping you from doing that?